# Laravel Eloquent: Find Action Performed By Function

Tags: database, laravel, orm, model, eloquent

My question concerns a few methods in the Laravel Eloquent ORM. Particularly, 3 methods have caught my attention:

```
firstOrCreate
firstOrNew
updateOrCreate
```

I clearly understand what these methods do but did not find a way to determine which operation was performed after calling them.

For example, after calling `firstOrCreate`, how do I figure out if the model was found in the database or created? I can run a find query first and then create the record if it was not found but that would be very inefficient.

Similarly, how to find out if an object was created or found in the database in case of `firstOrNew` and if the object was updated or created in case of `updateOrCreate`.

Comment: Why do you need this information? These function are shortcuts for code thats usually written anyway. If you need to determine which one was actually run you probably want to find and the see if anything is returned

Answer (score 0):

provided you have the timestamps turned on for those tables you could simply check their values in the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

The "exists" property will return true if the model is backed by the database (false if "new" occurred).

The "wasRecentlyCreated" property will return true if the record was just created (false if it already existed).

This should let you disambiguate between all the cases you mentioned.